# Calculate Number of worked_days in Given month from Deployment data (Mysql/PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

I am working on Payroll System where an employee can be deployed on projects from *any_date* to *any_date*. Sample MySQL table below

```
id   empid  project_id     start_date                end_date 
1      1       2        2016-11-05 15:10:22    2016-12-11 15:11:21 
2      1       3        2016-12-13 15:26:10    2016-12-20 15:29:40 
3      1       2        2016-12-23 15:31:46    2017-01-18 15:32:35
```

Now, if I want to calculate the number of days in **given month** worked on all projects, I am using Eloquent which translates to below query(I verified in `DB::getQueryLog())`:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
    payroll_project_tracks
WHERE
    empid = 1
        AND '2016-12-01 00:00:00' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
        AND '2016-12-31 23:59:59' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

After getting the rows that have deployments of given month (month = Dec 2016 here), I want to calculate Number of Days worked on *all projects in a given month.*

I am getting no results with the above query. Can anyone correct me or let me know if there is some better way of doing this.

Comment: The query is generated from what?

Comment: Have you tried running the query via phpmyadmin (or whatever interface you have to access the database)?

Comment: @mfisher91 yes I tried to run the query via phpmyadmin but no results.

Comment: @JRsz it's in Laravel 5.4

Comment: If you have influence to the query: I think this use of between should be placed befor the where part.

Comment: Try using `WHERE empid = 1 AND your_date >= start_date AND your_date <= end_date`

Comment: @mfisher91 I have two dates to consider, month_start and month_end because I'm trying to fetch all rows in given month.. (also start_date may be in previous months and end_date may be in next months) Hope you understood what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the query should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM payroll_project_tracks
WHERE
     empid = 1 AND
     start_date <= '2016-12-31 23:59:59' AND
     end_date >= '2016-12-01 00:00:00'
```

This query will return the 3 rows you provided, but will cut out the following:

```
4   1   2   2017-01-01 15:31:46 2017-01-18 15:32:35
```

is this ok?

Comment: cutting out the next month's days is ideal and exactly what I wanted.. The query seems to be to the point. I'll verify once on the App and then accept the answer. Thanks :)